# how to call an external URL from Teamcity Powershell or Commandline in Teamcity

Tags: jquery, powershell

I configured teamcity and adding build steps. In one of my build step I have to invoke my external server address is here http://localhost.server:8080/createsamplepage.php?build_id=%teamcity.build.id% . How to call external URL from Powershell or From CommandLine in TeamCity. 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [Invoke-Request](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) cmdlet

```
$url = "http://localhost.server:8080/createsamplepage.php?build_id=%teamcity.build.id%"
Write-Host "Opening URL: $url"
Invoke-WebRequest $url
```

Comment: Invoke method shows error.                                        [22:03:00][Step 2/4] Invoke-WebRequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet
[22:03:00][Step 2/4] Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch
[22:03:00][Step 2/4] configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try
[22:03:00][Step 2/4] again.
[22:03:00][Step 2/4] At line:1 char:1

Comment: Seems IE is not yet configured. See the workarounds listed here. https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/734056/invoke-webrequest-ie-error

Answer (score 2):

I resolved simply by adding the switch -UseBasicParsing to the Invoke-webrequest call. So for the example Invoke-webRequest $url -UseBasicParsing

I would guess that this switch is similar to Load IE with No add-ons.